# CSS drop down issue in IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a CSS based 2 level drop down menu which works just fine in FireFox, Chrome, and IE (before 10).  In IE 10, the drop downs don't work.  I have tried both standard and quirks mode, and it just flat does not work in IE 10.  I have taken apart the menu and I just can't figure out what is missing here.

The site is live at http://www.cmftexas.org and the menu in question is the top grey/black bar on each page.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

TIA,
-- Jeff

Comment: Your posted URL leads to a "page not found"

Comment: Strage, it works when I click on it.  What browser are you using and is it still showing the base http://www.cmftexas.org url or is it redirecting somewhere else?

Comment: I tried Firefox, Chrome and IE 11 and all say "page not found" or the "connection was reset". The URL doesnt redirect me anywhere. Perhaps this is an internal website you working on?

Comment: I would check this forum. http://www.swmenupro.com/forums/45.html. This looks like the plugin + version your are using.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may want to update your transmenu plugin.

http://www.swmenupro.com/forums/45/12101.html